# How to use tabIndex (maybe?) with Angular components?

Tags: angular-dart

I have several **material-input** :

```
   <span *ngFor="let field of listfields">
        <material-input #keyp (keyup.tab)="keyupEnter(field,keyp.inputText,keyp)"
                        label="Edit {{getDisplayStr(field)}}"
                        floatingLabel="true"
                        [ngModel]="getFieldValue(field)">
        </material-input>
```

When the user presses *enter*, the data is saved, but the focus remains on the current **material-input**. I would like it to automatically move focus / tab to the next **material-input** component. I can manually tab, and it works.

I have tried using (keyup.tab) (replacing keyup.enter), but the **inputText** is for the next (newly focused) **material-input**.

I looked into firing of a keyboard tab event, but that seems not to be allowed.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to angular_components but for any angular app you could do this in the form parent:
    @ViewChildren(MaterialInputComponent)
    QueryList materialInputs;

```
void onEnter(KeyboardEvent event, MaterialInputComponent input) {
  event.preventDefault();
  final inputs = materialInputs.toList();
  var index = inputs.indexOf(input) + 1;
  if (index >= inputs.length) index = 0;
  inputs[index].focus();
}
```

Then do this in the template:

```
<span *ngFor="let field of listfields">
  <material-input #keyp (keyup.enter)="onEnter($event, keyp)"
                label="Edit {{getDisplayStr(field)}}"
                floatingLabel="true"
                [ngModel]="getFieldValue(field)">
  </material-input>
```